# indexOf will not work in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object which is clearly a string, because I can access the string on it:
`console.log(sender)` will show Fri Mar 02 2018 09:00:20 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), which is obviously a string.

Now, when I try and do this:

```
 if (sender.indexOf("(GMT Standard Time)") !== -1)
```

I am told "sender.indexOf is not a function..."

I am using angularJS version 1.4.9

If it is of any relevance, when I hover over sender, it shows "(parameter) sender: any"

any what ???

Comment: You need `sender.toString().indexOf(...)`. Otherwise the type is `Date` or `object`

Comment: It's an object then, not a string. Your starting point is wrong.

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately this is what happens when you have to learn AngularJS without being a javascript ninja.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to string before using indexof, currently you have a Date type value

```
if (sender.toString().indexOf("(GMT Standard Time)") !== -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this example your code should work - thus your `sender` is not a string:

```js
var sender = 'Fri Mar 02 2018 09:00:20 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)'

if (sender.indexOf("(GMT Standard Time)") !== -1) alert(true)
```

try to use:

```
if (sender.toString().indexOf("(GMT Standard Time)") !== -1) alert(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

this means **sender** isn't a string object so you need to convert it to string before calling **indexOf** function

```
if(typeof sender !== 'string') sender = sender.toString();
if (sender.indexOf("(GMT Standard Time)") !== -1){
   // your code here
}
```

for details you can see [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: toString() was the key - brilliant!